# How to tag a label (figure, equation,...) or citation to a word inside the text?

Tags: links

I recently saw this helpful forum and really liked it.
I wonder if it is possible to tag a special label and also citation to a hyperlinked word inside the context, as I click on the word it jumps into the label or citation bibliography.
I used `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` but it works only for the case that both target and word are in the context. Thank you in advance.
By `\href` I can make a string hyperlinked, on which I click it jumps into, for example, a url or local file. Is it possible to make it for a label or citation, as I click on a string goes to the label or citation bibliography.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This isn't really a forum but a Question/Answer site. At the moment, your question is a little bit unclear

Comment: Usually **hyperref** makes those links for you automatically if you just load the package with the right options (including the defaults, I think). So I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you without your having to do anything at all.

Comment: \href{filename\#target}{text}